# Custom Listview using Base adapter not scrolls fast in Android

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am working with android application which is having custom listview. The items in listview around 3000. My problem is after loading items when scrolling it makes outOfMemory Error.

I am using Base Adapter and Each item having One Checkbox and four textviews.

Here is my code. Please let me know the solution.

```
public class GuestListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
    private String strExe;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    String sId;
    String sCheckIn;
    String strCheckInResponse;

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListId;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListFirstName;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListLastName;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListGuests;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayCustomOne;
    private ArrayList<String> arTempId;
    public static ArrayList<Boolean> chickinlist;

    public static ArrayList<Integer> arrCheckedItems;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> arrUnCheckedItems;
    Button btnInfo;
    private SQLiteAdapter mySqliteAdapter;
    private GuestListScreen myGuestList;
    private RelativeLayout views;
    private String strAlertValue;

    // private AlertDialog alertDialog = null;

    private ArrayList<Boolean> checks = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public GuestListAdapter(Context mcontext, ArrayList<String> arrListid,
            ArrayList<String> arrListFN, ArrayList<String> arrListLN,
            ArrayList<String> arrListGuest, ArrayList<String> arrTiketID,
            ArrayList<String> arrCustOne, ArrayList<Boolean> chicklist) {

        clearAdapter();

        arrayListId = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayListFirstName = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayListLastName = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayListGuests = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayCustomOne = new ArrayList<String>();
        arTempId = new ArrayList<String>();
        chickinlist = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        arrCheckedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arrUnCheckedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        arrayListId = arrListid;
        arrayListFirstName = arrListFN;
        arrayListLastName = arrListLN;
        arrayListGuests = arrListGuest;
        arrayCustomOne = arrCustOne;
        arTempId = arrTiketID;
        chickinlist = chicklist;

        context = mcontext;
        mySqliteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(context);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListFirstName.size(); i++) {
            checks.add(i, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return arrayListFirstName.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return arrayListFirstName.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        final int pos = position;
        views = null;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        views = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflator.inflate(
                R.layout.guest_list_item, null);

        final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) views.getChildAt(0);
        // Log.d("", "CheckBox Pos "+position);
        chk.setId(position);

        TextView txtView = (TextView) views.getChildAt(1);

        TextView txtView2 = (TextView) views.getChildAt(2);
        TextView txtView3 = (TextView) views.getChildAt(3);

        final TextView txtView4 = (TextView) views.getChildAt(4);
        TextView txtView5 = (TextView) views.getChildAt(6);
        txtView5.setId(position);

        // Log.d("", "Button Pos "+position);
        txtView4.setId(position);

        txtView4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, InfoScreen.class);
                intent.putExtra("IDVALUE", arTempId.get(txtView4.getId()));
                intent.putExtra("IDVALUE", arrayListId.get(position));

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        for (int dd = 0; dd < arrayListFirstName.size(); dd++) {
            if (position == dd) {
                // Log.d("", "Passsing arr size " + chickinlist.size());
                Boolean result = chickinlist.get(position);
                // Log.d("", "After " + result);
                if (result == true) {
                    chk.setChecked(true);
                    arrCheckedItems.add(position);
                    views.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_checked);

                } else {
                    chk.setChecked(false);
                    arrUnCheckedItems.add(position);
                    views.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_unchecked);

                }

                txtView.setText(arrayListFirstName.get(position));
                txtView2.setText(arrayListLastName.get(position));
                txtView3.setText("(" + arrayListGuests.get(position) + ")");
                if (arrayCustomOne.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("0")
                        || arrayCustomOne.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(null)
                        || arrayCustomOne.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(
                                "(null)")) {
                    txtView5.setText("");
                } else {
                    txtView5.setText(arrayCustomOne.get(position));
                }

            }

        }

        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                mySqliteAdapter.openToWrite();

                sId = arrayListId.get(chk.getId());
                // Log.d("Adapter",
                // "Checked Temp Id "+arTempId.get(chk.getId()));


                if (isChecked) {

                    chk.setChecked(true);
                    arrCheckedItems.add(position);
                    strAlertValue = "1";
                    sCheckIn = "1";
                    strExe = "update ticket_details set checkin_status=1 where tempid="
                            + arTempId.get(chk.getId());
                    mySqliteAdapter.executeCheckQurey(strExe);
                    if (Util.getInstance(context).isTabletDevice()) {
                        buttonView
                                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablet_list_item_check);
                        Log.e("Tablet", "Tablet Checked ");
                    } else {
                        buttonView
                                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_checked);
                        Log.e("Device", "Device Checked ");
                    }

                    new CheckInUpdate().execute();
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);
                    builder.create();
                    builder.setMessage(arrayListFirstName.get(chk.getId())
                            + " " + arrayListLastName.get(chk.getId())
                            + " has been checked in.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {


                                    Intent intentNavGuestList = new Intent(
                                            context, GuestListScreen.class);
                                    intentNavGuestList
                                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                                    context.startActivity(intentNavGuestList);

                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }

                            }).show();

                    // Log.d("", "ID = " + buttonView.getId());

                }
                if (!isChecked) {

                    sCheckIn = "0";
                    strAlertValue = "0";


                    strExe = "update ticket_details set checkin_status=0 where tempid="
                            + arTempId.get(chk.getId());

                    mySqliteAdapter.executeCheckQurey(strExe);

                    if (Util.getInstance(context).isTabletDevice()) {
                        buttonView
                                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablet_list_item_uncheck);
                        Log.e("Tablet", "Tablet UnChecked ");
                    } else {
                        buttonView
                                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_unchecked);
                        Log.e("Device", "Device UnChecked ");
                    }
                    new CheckInUpdate().execute();


                    Intent intentNavGuestList = new Intent(context,
                            GuestListScreen.class);
                    intentNavGuestList
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    context.startActivity(intentNavGuestList);



                }

            }
        });

        return views;

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Integer index = (Integer) view.getTag();
        boolean state = checks.get(index.intValue());

        checks.set(index.intValue(), !state);
    }


    public void clearAdapter() {
        if (arrayListFirstName != null) {

            arrayListFirstName.clear();
            arrayListId.clear();
            arrayListId = null;
            arrayListFirstName = null;
            arrayListLastName.clear();
            arrayListLastName = null;
            arrayListGuests.clear();
            arrayListGuests = null;
            arrayCustomOne.clear();
            arrayCustomOne = null;
            arTempId.clear();
            arTempId = null;
            chickinlist.clear();
            chickinlist = null;
            arrCheckedItems.clear();
            arrCheckedItems = null;
            arrUnCheckedItems.clear();
            arrUnCheckedItems = null;
        }

    }


}
```

I also tried with View Holder but still loading slow. Please tell the solution how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to reuse `view` paremeter from `View getView(final int position, Vie view, ViewGroup parent)` and if it's not null, then You don't need to inflate again.
2. Use ViewHolder pattern;
3. remove `loop for (int dd = 0; dd < arrayListFirstName.size(); dd++)` from getView;
4. Try simplify layout for list items;
5. Seems `arrayListFirstName.size()` can be simplified (e.g. use some variable to avoid `size()` calls)
6. Do [profiling](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) in order to know exactly what is slow downs You scrolling (It might be enough to profike only `getView()`)

Also, check out [this video from Google I/O](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) for more details on how to make ListViews in a right way.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I already tried if(view ==null) inflate else view = (Relative)views.getTag(); ... But still loading slows the scroll

Comment: It definitely should be much faster than without it. Also, ViewHolder should speed up scrolling. However, it might be still slow just because of very complex list items. Have You tried profiling http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html in order to determine root-cause? May be it's not the adapter at all?